# Plotly: WebGL plots are fuzzy/blurry

Tags: plotly, webgl, r-plotly

When I produce SVG plots with Plotly, I have no problems. When I produce WebGL plots, the plotted points aren't nearly as sharp: they are "fuzzy" or "blurry." I am using plotly.js 1.54.1. (And I'm using it mainly through plotly-r 4.9.2.1, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.)

Here is a minimal demonstration of the problem, using R to create a subplot:

```
library(plotly)
data(iris)
mySVG <- plot_ly(
  x      = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width,
  type   = "scatter", mode  = "markers",  
  color  = ~Species,
  data   = iris,
  marker = list(size = 10))
myWebGL <- toWebGL(mySVG)
subplot(mySVG, myWebGL, nrows = 2)
```

It produces [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ST3.png). The left-hand panel, an SVG plot, is notably sharper than the right-hand panel, which is a WebGL plot. Why are Plotly's WebGL plots so fuzzy?

The problem has been noted a few times in the Plotly.js Github repo: for example, https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3246 and https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2431. (The latter issue is framed as a problem with Plotly's handling of the hsl color model, but blurry rendering arises even when we don't use that model.)

The problem isn't specific to retina screens. My own monitor is only 110 dpi, and the problem is acute even on that sort of monitor.

Things I've tried:

- Changing the `glPixelRatio` option that is used when the plots are set up.
- Manipulating the `canvas` element of the WebGL plots. I read that fuzziness can arise when `canvas.width` and `canvas.clientWidth` are not the same. But that isn't a problem here. (The same is true for `canvas.height` and `canvas.clientHeight`.)
- Using Plotly.newplot() to re-render a plot, per [this comment](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3246#issuecomment-439175019).

None of that has worked. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is some discussion at https://community.plotly.com/t/webgl-plots-are-blurry/41716. One of the messages on that thread is that SVG is vector and WebGL is pixelated, which makes it tricky to raise WebGL to SVG quality. But the thread also suggests that there's an outstanding pull request that may be helpful.

Edit 2021-12-10: [version 4.9.3 of the "plotly" package for R incorporates plotly v1.57.1](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/NEWS.md). Upgrading to this version of the "plotly" package for R may solve the problem. (I haven't yet tested the example code in the post with this latest version of the R package.)

Edit 2020-10-23: the relevant pull requests in [plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js) are [#3637](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/3637) and -- especially -- [#5093](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/5093). #5093 was merged into plotly.js 1.55.0, but that version [hasn't yet been incorporated](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/NEWS.md) into the "plotly" package for R.